# Disable Weekends (Sat & Sun) using ngx-bootstrap BsDatePicker

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am using Ngx-bootstrap date-picker in my angular 5 application.

How to disable weekends(Sat & Sun) in the datepicker?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't yet supported in ngx-bootstrap, but there seems to be an open issue that the valor-software team is aware of

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/1657

The workaround now would be to handle each click and disable if the click is not a weekday